# Skype wants to make changes to the computer every time it starts

Tags: windows-7, permissions, boot, skype, uac

For a few days every time I start Skype I get an UAC prompt from Windows 7 about Skype wanting to make changes to my computer and whether I want to allow it.

Why Skype needs elevated permissions all of sudden? Anyone else experiences this?

Version: 4.2.0.155

Comment: if there's a screen shot, it'll be helpful. :)

Comment: It's a standard UAC prompt in windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Skype most probably wants to update yourself, as you're using an outdated version. Current version is 5.5, and yours is 4.2. In order to install an update, it needs to elevate to Administrator.

I didn't find a way to disable updates in Skype, at least in version 5.5, so I guess you either need to update to a latest version, or live with this nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

I just say "No" to the prompt. I am yet to find a feature that breaks after I reject UAC elevation.

(and then I send them a feedback item about this - let's all do so!)

Answer (score 0):

If Skype needs administrator privileges to run, there is still a way to avoid the UAC prompt:

[How to Create a Elevated Program Shortcut without a UAC Prompt](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html)

Comment: The problem is I use Autohotkey to send typing shortcuts to Skype and apparently it does not work if Skype is started as administrator (probably for security reasons).

So the question is why Skype needs admin privileges all of a sudden when it didn't need it before?

Comment: He's after a "why is this happening" response. It's obvious that Skype needs administrator permission because of the UAC, but *why* it wants it is a mystery that @Tom wants solved.

Comment: @Ashley: This is an old thread. My answer would be useful if the UAC problem was never resolved.

Comment: Wow yeah very sorry... didn't see it was so old. No idea how I ended up on this thread...